# MySQL with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I've been trying to add an EF Model for my MySQL server but couldn't get a chance as it would either close right before choosing the Entity Framework version for my project or give "Your project references the latest version of Entity Framework, howerver, an entity database provider compatible with this version could not be found for your data connection" error and I'm unable to choose the EF 6.x for it.

Versions: Entity Framework 6.2.0, Mysql.Data 8.11.00, Mysql.Data.Entity 6.10.7.0, Connector/Net 8.11.0.0

[Here's a gif for the first incident.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GS4br.gif)

[Here's a screenshot for the second incident.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XglM4.png)

So far I've tried:

1. Installing Mysql.Data.Entity from NuGet Package Manager and editing the app.config file according to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html) guide.
2. Installing lower versions of Entity Framework and that wouldn't cause an error and I would be able to choose EF 5.x and then the window would close immediately.
3. Adding the Mysql.Data, Mysql.Data.EntityFramework references directly from the Connector's directory.
4. Installing EF 6 first, Mysql.Data.Entity second and vice-versa.

Unfortunately, none of these worked. I've been told that there was a bug related to this exact error before but they said it's been fixed after the update and I'd be able to use it bug-free if I install the packages from NuGet. I don't know if it's a bug though.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure following applications are installed.

1. MySQL Connector for .NET [Download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/) (might require c++ runtime >=2015, check the mysql site)
2. MySQL for visual studio [Download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/visualstudio/1.2.html)

You can mange your MySQL products using MySQL for windows [Download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/5.7.html)

I haven't tried with the new 8.0 connectors but can confirm the 6.10.xx versions had some Nuget package errors on some PC. (Would complain about missing runtime dlls.. 6.9.11 would work perfectly)

Comment: So are you suggesting 6.9.11? Where can I download that? I installed connector from MySQL Installer.

Comment: On mysql site you can download previous versions.

Comment: I only see 6.9.12. No downloads for 6.9.11 displayed, unfortunately.

Comment: @ümit hacıyusufoğlu use nuget in VS they have all the versions