# Mysql.data entity not working in visual studio 2019

Tags: mysql, visual-studio

I would like mysql.data.entity to work in visual studio but I get this error I have tried many solution but none have worked for me. I am using the newest version of visual studio.

[image: mysql error]

Here si my webconfig

```
  <entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
      <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

I can provide any other information i might be forgetting.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL with Entity Framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50631210/mysql-with-entity-framework-6)

Comment: It dose not fix my problem since I am using the newest version of visual studio.